# CNTK & Python: How to do reflect or symmetric padding instead of zero padding?

Tags: python, padding, cntk

In the cntk.layers package we have the option to do zero padding:

**pad** (bool or tuple of bools, defaults to False) – if False, then the filter will be shifted over the “valid” area of input, that is, no value outside the area is used. If pad=True on the other hand, the filter will be applied to all input positions, and positions outside the valid region will be considered containing zero. Use a tuple to specify a per-axis value.

But how can I use other types of padding like reflect or symmetric padding?
Is it possible to integrate my own padding criterion in the cntk.layers?

I'm a beginner in cntk and really grateful for every help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new pad operation (in master; will be released with CNTK 2.2) that supports reflect and symmetric padding.